# Covariant derivative commutator on spinors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, curvature, spinors, differential-geometry

What is this object $[\nabla_{\mu},\nabla_{\nu}]\epsilon$
in terms of curvature tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$?

Where $\nabla_{\mu}$ is the covariant derivative on a four sphere and $\epsilon$ is spinor.

PS: I suppose that it could not be useful but the spinor satisfy the Killing equation
$$
\nabla_{\mu}\epsilon=\frac{\gamma_5\gamma_{\mu}}{2}\epsilon.
$$

Comment: 1. Is this a gauge covariant derivative or the Levi-Civita covariant derivative? 2. Is $R_{\mu\nu}$ the Ricci tensor or the curvature tensor of a connection? 3. Can you ask about something more conceptual than "What is $X$ in terms of $Y$?" without giving any indication why $X$ should be in terms of $Y$ or what you have done to compute this?

Comment: "..is the covariant derivative on a four sphere". I mean Levi-Civita covariant derivative i thought it was clear, and the tensor is the Ricci tensor.

Answer (score 0):

The covariant derivative of a field have values in the Lorentz algebra in the representation of the field, spinorial representation in this case, I.e.,
$$\mathcal{J}^{ab} = - \frac{\imath}{4}[\gamma^a,\gamma^b].$$
Thus the covariant derivative for spinors is
$$\nabla_\mu \epsilon = \partial_\mu \epsilon + \frac{\imath}{2} \omega_\mu{}^{ab}\mathcal{J}_{ab},$$
where $\omega$ is the spin connection (I'm assuming that you are familiar with the formalism of tetrads).

I'm leaving the algebra for you (specially because I'm writing from a tablet, and is closer to midnight), but the rsult should be something like:
$$[\nabla_\mu , \nabla_\nu] \epsilon = \frac{\imath}{2} \mathcal{R}_{\mu\nu}{}^{ab} \mathcal{J}_{ab} \epsilon = \frac{\imath}{2} \boldsymbol{\mathcal{R}}_{\mu\nu} \epsilon. $$

**PLEASE NOTICE**: It is not the Ricci tensor what is envolved in the equation, but the components of the 2-form curvature with values in the algebra.